# Contradictory answers while integrating $\int \frac{dH}{kS-kH}$

Tags: integration, substitution

Note: I use $\cdot$ to signify multiplication.

We could either have:

$$\int \frac{dH}{kS-kH} = \frac1k \int \frac{dH}{S-H} = \frac1k \cdot -\ln|S-H|+C$$

Or we could use $u$-substitution instead:

$$u=kS-kH \Rightarrow du =-k\cdot dH \Rightarrow \frac{du}{-k} =dH  $$

$$\int \frac{dH}{kS-kH} = \int \frac1u \frac{du}{-k}= \frac1{-k}\int \frac1u du = \frac1{-k} \ln|u|+C = \frac1{-k} \ln|kS-kH|+C$$

As far as I can tell, $$ \frac1k \cdot -\ln|S-H|+C \neq \frac1{-k} \ln|kS-kH|+C$$

because $$\ln|kS-kH| = \ln|k|+ \ln|S-H|  \neq  \ln|S-H|$$

so I have a contradiction. (Unless $k=\pm e$, which isn't guaranteed.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing going wrong in either of the cases.

The value constant of integration in the two  cases is different, so it will not make any contradiction.

C1=C2-ln (k)/k

See that ln (k) is a constant.